# first project, ios simulator view cut off

Tags: ios

This is my first ios app and I am doing a simple project with button.  I notice soon as I run simulator the simulator is not displaying the whole screen.
I must be missing something very silly.

any ideas?

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: More information, please. iPad Simulator or iPhone Simulator? How did you add the button? Using a Storyboard? If so, how did you position it?

Comment: iphone Simulator.. changed to i5s in xcode... top left of screen.  and in simulator hardware simulator.  I dragged button into storyboard and let it automatically align to middle of the screen

Comment: Use The [View Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) tool. That might show you something worthwhile.

Comment: Check my answer. Your solution can be 3rd one (very likely)

Comment: Your views are not sized properly; the simulator is displaying everything that would display on a phone. You can tell because the battery icon is in the right spot.

Comment: I just looked at view debugging tool, the boxes I added/button are way off the screen area

Comment: You need to add constraints to your `UIButton`. Basic explanation: you have added a button to a screen in IB with the size class set to `Any/Any`. When you run in the iPhone simulator the size class is `Compact Width/Regular Height` and the `UIButton` is now off to the right. This is because if you don't add constraints everything is assumed to be static. There are many tutorials about this on the web but I recommend following `Developing iOS Apps With Swift` on iTunesU. If you're using Objective-C is still very useful.

Comment: thank you... playing around with auto-layout and constraints seems to move things around.  I'll go read up on some tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add Constraints to your UITextField and your UIButton.
Open up your Storyboard, select your View (your TextField or your Button) and add the Constraints for example as it is in the Picture.

[image]

Comment: Image is as a Link because of too less Reputation ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your UITextView programmatically then its very likely that you have not set proper width. Just shorten the width programmatically.

Or

If you have dragged and dropped it then re-adjust it by decreasing it with your cursor.

Or

It is because you have set the UITextView and UIButton in a larger version of iPhone and running in lower version . i.e You must have set the controls in iPhone 6 or 6+ and you might be running it in iPhone 4 or 5.

Comment: how do I set controls for i5?

Comment: There are 3 possible solution to this.  1) Use Auto Layout 2) Create your controls programmatically 3) Create different xibs

Comment: First you should try to run it in iPhone 6 or 6+ and see that are you still getting your view cut or not?

Comment: i switched xcode device AND simulator to iphone6 and it is still being cut off

Comment: switch xcode to 6+ and better but still not aligned properly.  even the storyboard visual looks very wide.  like a plus phone... not like the 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70252/discussion-between-solarissf-and-rahul).